# How to wait till an ajax function is finished in show callback (qtip2)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, qtip2

I am using `qtip2` for tolltips:

```
function setupTolltip() {
    $("g path").each(function () {
        var path = $(this);
        var sessionId = $("#rsr").attr("data-session");
        var clientId = $("#rsr").attr("data-client");
        $(this).qtip(
            {
                content: {
                    text: function () {
                        var allPlaces = $(this).attr("data-all");
                        var freePlaces = $(this).attr("data-free");
                        var price = $(this).attr("data-price");
                        var tooltipText = "<div>All: " + allPlaces + "<br/>Free: " + freePlaces + "<br/> Price: " + price + "</div>";
                        return tooltipText;
                    }
                },
                events: {
                    show: function () {
                        var levelId = path.attr("level");
                        updateLevelInfo(path, levelId, sessionId, clientId);

                    }
                },
                position: {
                    target: 'mouse',
                    adjust: {
                        x: 10
                    }
                },
                style: {
                    classes: 'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow',
                    tip: true
                }
            });
    });
}
```

When tooltip shows I make call `updateLevelInfo` function. This function make ajax request and updating attribute which uses `qtip`. The problem in that this is ajax request( I can't use `$.get`) and tooltip shows before function finish executed.

Comment: where is the `updateLevelInfo` function ? and `$.get` is just shorthand for `$.ajax`

Comment: Have you considered the use of the callback [beforeshow](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#callbacks)?

Comment: You may have no control over this. QTip clearly provides a callback mechanism on show, but whether it will allow you to delay the show whilst the callback does something asynchronous, I'm not sure - only the QTip docs would tell you that. If not, your only route would be to hack the script yourself or manually hide the tooltip then show it when ready, essentially overriding the functionality of QTip itself.

Comment: @ManseUK: I can't use because there are cross - domain request. It's not works with `async:false`.

Comment: @BasWildeboer: this is for qtip version 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the [AJAX Object](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/plugins/ajax/) used in [this official demo](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax)?

You should always show a "loading" Information or Image, so there is no problem if your tooltip is shown before loading your content. (Again see [Ajax Demo](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax))

if you want to use `show` functionality then please use `show: function(event, api)` (see [this example](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/api/events/#show)). Then use the var `api` and give it into your function:

`updateLevelInfo(path, levelId, sessionId, clientId, api);`

Then you are able to manipulate the tooltip after doing your staff in your function!

Comment: I'm using svg. When svg is loaded I make the ajax request( cross-domain) and fill attributes(`data-all`, `data-free`, 'data-price') which uses qtip. When mouse over the path I want update this attribute.

Comment: @user1260827 i do not really get your problem: please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your core functionality so that i can provide you with a customized solution.